# In which file final centroids are stored after clustering in Mahout

Tags: cluster-computing, mahout, k-means

I am running a `KMeans` clustering algorithm in Mahout. I am using `KMeansDriver.run` function as I am using Hadoop too.
I want to know that in which file the `final centroids` are stored. Is this the same file as we provide for initial cluster.
Also I want to ask whats the meaning of `part-m` and `part-r` files generated?

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in centroid folder under centroid-final. 
part-m is output of mapper I.e there is no reduce job
part-r is output of reducer